# Incorrect alignment when sending ASCII Art via SMS and Email in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email, sms, ascii-art

In my iPhone app, I have ASCII art, which I am sharing via email and SMS.

I have inserted the ASCII art into the Sqlite database along with the newline character and spaces.

Problem is when I send them through SMS and Email, the whole ASCII art comes in left alignment and spacing between characters is lost.

ASCII Art fetched in Label in my app is as below

[image]

Same ASCII Art when inserted to Email API (MFMailComposeViewController) is as below

[image]

Same ASCII Art when inserted to SMS API (MFMessageComposeViewController) is as below

[image]

How to maintain the spaces? How to make the ASCII art look proper in Mail as well as SMS API View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's because of the font. If you use in your App courier new then each space would have the same gap like a normal character but in other fonts they are not the same. You can try and replace each space with double space perhaps it will look nice again.

You can set html to your `MFMailComposeViewController` so to force spaces you can use `'&nbsp;'` or `'&#160;'` instead of `' '`

Also, before showing your composer view you can change an attribute to display html (`[mailComposer setMessageBody:myHtmlString isHTML:YES];`) where `myHtmlString` represent this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
body {font-family: courier new; 
font-size: 10pt; 
color: 00000; 
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
your ascii art here
</body> 
</html>
```

To expand on my second advice, replace each space with double space:

```
[asciiArtString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"  "];
```

Comment: iPortable : Thanks for your input, I am using courier new in my app but the thing is that how can we control the font type in MFMailComposeViewController class, which is an in built API for mail. I give the same ASCII art to the label and textview in my app and there it looks fine. But when I give the label value to the Email API then it trims the spaces and becomes left aligned. What can be done in that case?

Comment: I know that you can commit formatted text to MFMailComposeViewController. basic html should solve your problem ;) ... see edit

Comment: iPortable: I have added the screenshots in my question. So that you can get a better idea about what is happening. Can you explain more about basic html that you just said.Sorry I didnt get what needs to be done.

Comment: iPortable : I just tried putting &nbsp; in place of " " but it didnt help. The ASCII art still comes as before. What can be done in this case? Also if I set it to HTML then the newline characters are not recognized and the whole ASCII art comes in one single line.

Comment: Where do need to write all this HTML tags?

Comment: replace each newline with <br/> (or <br>?)

Comment: iPortable: As such I have added your code and looks like it works fine for email but does not seem to work for SMS yet. What can be done for SMS API? I have added a screenshot of SMS API in my Question.

Comment: I never done something with SMS and I don't know if its even possible. A SMS only contains characters (not html) and is displayed on each device different. They will place the newline where the display ends. For example on my Motorola F3 it would only show 7 chars a time. My advice: either you completely remove the SMS function or you let the user copy'n'paste your string (I don't know if its even then would work)